# How to convert dates to specific formats in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm having trouble converting dates to php, what conversion would this date be for first? `2021-10-04T09:49:50.636-04:00`.

In the documentation this format is ISO 8601, but it doesn't look like ISO 8601.

Ex:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$format = new DateTime($today);
$expires = $format->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
echo $expires; //2021-10-04T09:49:50-0300
```

Are extremely different:

```
2021-10-04T09:49:50-0300 ISO 8601
2021-10-04T09:49:50.636-04:00 The format I don't know
```

How can I convert my current date date() to this format?: 
`2021-10-04T09:49:50.636-04:00`

Comment: They're not _that_ much different...the `.636` is just the addition of milliseconds, and there's a `:` in the timezone bit, that's all. You can specify a custom format as per the description [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Not clear why you're expecting 4 instead of 3 for the timezone offset though?

Comment: Looks like `DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED` is the format you want.

Comment: @ADyson All right

Answer (score 0):

DateTime automatically recognizes many date formats. So also "2021-10-04T09: 49: 50.636-04: 00" (DateTime :: RFC3339_EXTENDED).
To create a DateTime object, you don't have to know the exact name.

```
$strDate = "2021-10-04T09:49:50.636-04:00";
$dt = new DateTime($strDate);
/*
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => "2021-10-04 09:49:50.636000",
   'timezone_type' => 1,
   'timezone' => "-04:00",
))
*/
```

Creating a DateTime object for today 00:00 is also easy:

```
$dt = new DateTime('today');
```

Examples of special output formats:

```
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601)."<br>";
echo $dt->format(DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED)."<br>";
/*
2021-10-04T09:49:50-0400
2021-10-04T09:49:50.636-04:00
*/
```

If you want to know what is behind a class constant like DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED then let it show you with PHP:

```
echo DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED; //Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP
```